# Как реализовать схему создания и подключения сервера?

Tags: java, android, клиент-сервер

Если кто играл в игру Дукрак Онлайн (или любое подобное многопользовательское приложение) на андроид, то там есть возможность создания своего сервера и подключения к нему.
Как я понимаю сервер создается на удаленном компьютере. Вот и у меня возник вопрос, как такое можно реализовать: создание нового сервера с android-устройства на удаленном компьютере.

Или это делается иначе? Например заранее запущены сервера, а когда на устройстве жмется "Создать игру(сервер)", он становится видимым и на нем меняются настройки...

P.S. Так же хотел бы узнать насчет мониторинга серверов, к которым можно подключится. Поиск и отображение доступных серверов реализуется в отдельном потоке в бесконечном while цикле? Или есть решение с более "красивой" реализацией?

Answer (score 2):

Заранее создается приложение-сервер и размещается на удаленном физическом сервере. "Создать игру(сервер)" - лучше понимать как создание комнаты или для карточной игры - создание партии. В карточной игре к такой партии потом подключаются другие игроки. Заранее создавать сервера, комнаты или партии нету необходимости. Лучше создавать эти сущности по требованию, например когда игрок выбирает опцию "Создать игру(сервер)", после чего они в том или ином виде становятся видимыми другим игрокам.

Вариантов мониторинга серверов (комнат, партий) на клиенте несколько. Это сильно зависит от выбранной клиент-серверной архитектуры. Если выбрана архитектура на постоянных соединениях (TCP или UDP сокеты) - между клиентом и сервером создается двусторонний канал связи - сервер по инициативе одного пользователя создает комнату и оповещает об этом событии остальных заинтересованных пользователей, например тех кто в это время просматривает список доступных комнат.

Comment: То есть получается, что изначально все запустившие приложение игроки подключаются к одному серверу, а потом уже распределяются по комнатам в зависимости от созданных ими же партиями? А партии это просто объект на сервере состоящий из подключенных к нему игроков?

Comment: На примере карточной игры - да. В более сложных играх необходимо реализовать более сложную схему. В многопользовательских играх рассчитанных на тысячи одновременно играющих игроков может быть несколько серверов.